# Overrriding ActiveRecord attribute getter doesn't produce consistent results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an attribute `priority` that is stored in database as an integer. I map them to specific values:

```
  PRIORITY = {
      high:1,normal:2,low:3
  }
```

When I want to access the reader, I override it as so:

```
  def priority
    PRIORITY.key(read_attribute(:priority))
  end
```

My problem is when I want to check if any attribute values have changed and I invoke the `changes` method, I get the following results:

```
task.changes
 => {"priority"=>[2, :high]}
```

For the original value, it takes the database value. For the changed value, it takes the result of the getter accessor value. It is inconsistent.

How can I make the `changes` call behave consistently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using an enum in your model, like below:

```
enum priority: { high: 1, normal: 2, low: 3}
```

see the documentation here http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: I never even came across this before. In which version of Rails is this available?

Comment: I think since rails 2 or 3, give it a try it will change your life or at least your code :)